# Enforce a max-height in CSS only when required

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have pictures that I'm going to be displaying that are 400x300 that'll be scaled in a div accordingly (as low as 200x150). Now because of the various display sizes, I won't know ahead of time to what size the images will be scaled, however, I want to enforce the 4:3 ratio.  Unfortunately in CSS there's no way to do something like this: `max-height: width * 1.3`, as far as I understand.

I tried this in jQuery but the max-height attribute got set to 0:
`$(".image").attr('max-height', $(".image").width() * 1.3 + "px");`

Is there anyway to accomplish this in pure CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Can you have `max-width`? That'd also solve your problem. EDIT: or set a width to container or image, no height and ratio will be kept

Comment: The width never changes, it's the height that is occaisionally variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(".image").css('max-height', $(".image").width() * 1.3 + "px");
```

`max-height` is a style property, not a DOM attribute.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same thing. +1

Comment: Should be `maxHeight`, isn't it?

Comment: Of course it's css not attrib. Clear example of a brain fart, thanks!